Constraining a type parameter to be a "safely comparable" type
I have generic code that uses the standard comparison operators. Because of that, I want to constrain the generic type to be one that is safely comparable. For example, string is safe, and number is safe, but string | number is not.
// We want K to be 'string' or 'number' or 'boolean' or 'Date'
declare function sort<K>(array: Array<K>): void;
declare function max<K>(a: K, b: K): void;
class BinaryTree<K, V> { constructor(private readonly k: K) {} }

// Should not error
function f1(r: string): void {
    sort([r, r]);
    max(r, r)
    new BinaryTree(r)
}
function f2(r: boolean): void {
    sort([r, r]);
    max(r, r)
    new BinaryTree(r)
}

// Should error
function f3(r: null): void {
    sort([r, r]);
    max(r, r)
    new BinaryTree(r)
}
function f4(r: string | number): void {
    sort([r, r]);
    max(r, r)
    new BinaryTree(r)
}
function f5(r: Array<string>): void {
    sort([r, r]);
    max(r, r)
    new BinaryTree(r)
}

Playground
There are hacks that work in some situations, e.g.:

array: Array<string> | Array<number> | Array<Date> | Array<boolean>
function signature overloads

But they get pretty verbose and messy.
Is there a way to keep using a type parameter, but just constrain it to what I want?

TS lacks a "one of these" generic constraint, as requested at ms/TS#27808. You can approximate this with a recursive constraint, possibly as shown in this playground link. (I can't tell if my suggestion is one of your "hacks"; you didn't demonstrate them in a [mre] so it's not clear, but either way, the issue is lack of ms/TS#27808.) Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what's missing?

That OneOf thing looks pretty good! I'd be interested in learning why it's just approximate, i.e. in what cases does it not work? (Either way, I think it's a good answer to the question.)

TypeScript doesn't have a way to say that a generic type argument should be exactly one of some set of types. If you constrain a type parameter to a union type then the type argument can be any subtype of that union, including the full union itself.  There is a longstanding open feature request at microsoft/TypeScript#27808 to support this sort of "one of" constraint, but it's not part of the language, and you'll need to work around that if you want to proceed.
If you are only trying to get this functionality from the caller's side of a call signature, then you can write a recursive generic constraint to get similar functionality. Instead of T extends_oneof A, B, C, you'd write T extends OneOf<T, [A, B, C]> where OneOf is defined as, say,
type OneOf<T, U extends any[]> =
    { [I in keyof U]: [T] extends [U[I]] ? U[I] : never }[number];

This works by mapping over the tuple type of the second type argument and checking if the type T is assignable to each member of the tuple in turn. If it is assignable to any of the members, then it succeeds, otherwise it fails.  For example, OneOf<string, [string, number]> evaluates to [string, never][number] which is string | never which is string, and since string extends string is true then it succeeds.  But OneOf<string | number, [string, number]> evaluates to [never, never][number] which is never | never which is never, and since string extends number is false then it fails.
So you could write
declare function sort<
    T extends OneOf<T, [string, number, boolean, Date]>
>(array: Array<T>): void;

declare function max<
    T extends OneOf<T, [string, number, boolean, Date]>
>(a: T, b: T): void;

and then you can verify that sort and max will reject string | number as well as other invalid inputs:
function f1(r: string): void {
    sort([r, r]); max(r, r); new BinaryTree(r) // okay
}
function f2(r: boolean): void {
    sort([r, r]); max(r, r); new BinaryTree(r) // okay
}
function f3(r: null): void {
    sort([r, r]); max(r, r); new BinaryTree(r) // error
}
function f4(r: string | number): void {
    sort([r, r]); max(r, r); new BinaryTree(r) // error
}
function f5(r: Array<string>): void {
    sort([r, r]); max(r, r); new BinaryTree(r) // error
}


Caveats: if you want to use this approach, you should test thoroughly against your intended use cases.  TypeScript doesn't "understand" what OneOf means, so it can't draw conclusions about it for arbitrary generic cases.
The biggest drawback is that the implementation of the function can't make use of the "one of" constraint. TypeScript doesn't see that as an invariant:
function foo<T extends OneOf<T, [string, number]>>(t: T, u: T) {
    if (typeof t === "string") {
        t.toUpperCase(); // okay
        u.toUpperCase(); // error!
    } else {
        t.toFixed(); // okay
        u.toFixed(); // error!
    }
}

If TypeScript understood that t and u were of a type T extends_oneof string, number, then checking the type of t would imply that u is the same type. But it doesn't; it treats both t and u as independent parameters of type string | number. This is no worse than without using OneOf, but it means that you really only get benefits of this from the caller's side.
A related drawback is that it also fails on the caller's side if the types being passed are themselves generic. If X, A, B, and C are specific types, TypeScript can just evaluate OneOf<X, [A, B, C]>. But if any of them are generic, then TypeScript mostly defers evaluation and so you'll end up getting errors you might not expect:
function bar<T extends string>(t: T, u: T) {
    max(t, u); // error!
    //  ~
    // Argument of type 'T' is not assignable to parameter of type '([T] extends [string] ? string : never) | 
    // ([T] extends [number] ? number : never) | ([T] extends [boolean] ? boolean : never) | 
    // ([T] extends [Date] ? Date : never)'.
}

TypeScript has no idea what OneOf<T, [string, number, boolean, Date]> is for generic T, so it just rejects everything, even when T extends string.  Presumably if microsoft/TypeScript#27808 were implemented, this functionality would be native to TypeScript and you wouldn't run into these problems.
Playground link to code
